# Do i need to file multiple design patents if the product can use different country plugs

Tags: patent-applications, design-patent

My design uses an integrated plug, for example US, EU, European plugs, do i need to file multiple design patents for the different plug options?

Or is one plug ok to show the ornamental design for the product?

The different plugs do not go on leads, instead they are part of the product.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in this, but I believe you can used dashed or broken lines to cover elements of the design that aren't to be covered by the patent. This is a [good article](http://www.ipwatchdog.com/2013/07/30/strong-design-patents-the-power-of-the-broken-line/id=44215/) explaining this. Based on this, I think you would draw the plug portion of your figures in broken lines. Here is the [USPTO guide](https://www.uspto.gov/patents-getting-started/patent-basics/types-patent-applications/design-patent-application-guide#broken). There is a section there about broken lines:

> Broken Lines
>
> A broken line disclosure is understood to be for illustrative purposes
>   only and forms no part of the claimed design. Structure that is not
>   part of the claimed design, but is considered necessary to show the
>   environment in which the design is used, may be represented in the
>   drawing by broken lines. This includes any portion of an article in
>   which the design is embodied or applied to that is not considered part
>   of the claimed design. When the claim is directed to just surface
>   ornamentation for an article, the article in which it is embodied must
>   be shown in broken lines.
>
> In general, when broken lines are used, they should not intrude upon
>   or cross the showing of the claimed design and should not be of
>   heavier weight than the lines used in depicting the claimed design.
>   Where a broken line showing of environmental structure must
>   necessarily cross or intrude upon the representation of the claimed
>   design and obscures a clear understanding of the design, such an
>   illustration should be included as a separate figure in addition to
>   the other figures which fully disclose the subject matter of the
>   design.